# Получить все объекты которые есть, по шаблону или без него

Tags: c++, pkcs#12

Хочу осуществить поиск всех объектов. В документации по Botan::PKCS11 нашел пример создания
объекта с последующим поиском его по шаблону. Это метод Botan::PKCS11::ObjectFinder.

Хорошо. А если мне нужно найти все объекты которые у меня есть. Как мне их найти?
Примерный код у меня такой.

```
Botan::PKCS11::Slot slot(m_module, slots.at(aSlotNumber));
Botan::PKCS11::Session session(slot, false);
    
Botan::PKCS11::AttributeContainer search_template;
search_template.add_string(Botan::PKCS11::AttributeType::Label, " ");

Botan::PKCS11::ObjectFinder finder(session, search_template.attributes());
auto search_result = finder.find();
finder.finish();
```

Как мне найти все объекты которые есть. А не те которые я сам создал и знаю их метку. Спасибо.
Что нужно передать в ObJectFinder чтобы получить вектор доступных объектов?

Comment: Пытаетесь заниматься хакерством?...

Comment: Нет )) Пишу свое приложение для работы с токеном.